# python mysql multi-row insert fail

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert

i'm just trying to insert data into a small mysql (innodb) table i made for testing. the single row insert works:

```
cursor.execute("insert into testy (one, two) values (%s,%s)", ('00','01'))
```

but multiple row insert fails:

```
cursor.execute("insert into testy (one, two) values (%s,%s)", [('00','01'),('10','11'),('20','21')])
```

and gives the following error:

```
TypeError - not all arguments converted during string formatting

traceback:
  File "./testy.py", line 20, in <module>
    cursor.execute("insert into testy (one, two) values (%s,%s)", [('00','01'),('10','11'),('20','21')])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
```

i need to do the multi-row insert as it is much quicker than looping over the single row inserts. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`executemany` method](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) instead of [`execute`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

```
cursor.executemany("insert into testy (one, two) values (%s,%s)",
                   [('00','01'),('10','11'),('20','21')])
```